# Signed apk does not keep the app in background

Tags: android, apk

My issue is like this, I press home button and go to home page, then I press the app icon to get back to the app. Instead of resuming the app it starts from the beginning. But if I select app from recent app list, it resumes. So, some unknown reason app starts from the beginning if I press app icon.

I'm getting this strange result with **signed** apk. **Unsigned/debug** apk works fine, it resumes.

Please note that, I've not handled any BackStack activities, neither handled any activity **android:launchMode**.

Comment: Can you post your manifest please?

Comment: Have you handled BackStack activities?

Comment: Nothing special done, No activity launchMode handled or BackStack handled.

Comment: try it in a different devise, maybe it has to do with the kernel.

Comment: Do you use proguard when signing your application. If yes, can you post the proguard configuration?

Answer (score 0):

At last I'm answering my own question. The issue is solved.

It turned out that Activity Standard LaunchMod (which is default settings) behaves like this in Some devices with OS v5.0 +. So, I added it to be **"launchMode"** in from menifest. So App works fine now. Although I'm still not sure about this behavior.